# How to compare two database structures?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sqlite, schemacrawler

I'm using **SQLite/Hibernate**. Idea is to check each time app starts whether database structure is up to date. I have my existing database in "DB" folder and each time app start I'm creating up to date database in "DB/structure" folder.

I want to compare them and if my existing database is old, copy data to up to date database. Get rid of old database and move fresh one in it's place.

So far I've tried **SchemaCrawler**, but I was getting errors with it and couldn't figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

I connected with SchemaCrawler to both databases:

```
public SchemaConroller() {

        SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
        options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.standard());

        Catalog catalog1=null;
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            catalog1 = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(conn, options);
            for (Schema schema : catalog1.getSchemas()) {
                System.out.println(schema);
                for (Table table : catalog1.getTables(schema)) {
                    System.out.println("o--> " + table + "    size: "+table.getColumns().size());
                    /*for (Column column : table.getColumns()) {
                        System.out.println("     o--> " + column);
                    }*/
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Catalog catalog2=null;
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection2();
            catalog2 = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(conn, options);
            for (Schema schema : catalog2.getSchemas()) {
                System.out.println(schema);
                for (Table table : catalog2.getTables(schema)) {
                    System.out.println("o--> " + table + "    size: "+table.getColumns().size());
                    /*for (Column column : table.getColumns()) {
                        System.out.println("     o--> " + column);
                    }*/
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(catalog1.equals(catalog2)){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>DATABASE IS UP TO DATE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        }else{
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>DATABASE IS OUT OF DATE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        }
    }
```

But I always get positive answer, if I try `catalog1 == catalog2` - I always get negative. How to properly compare data structure?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709777/which-jar-files-are-required-for-schemacrawler

Comment: Sualeh, not exactly. In that question, you pointed to, I was asking why it isn't connecting. While in this one I'm asking about examples how to do it using SchemaCrawler or any other plugin. Unfortunately there are not many examples available.

Comment: How can I compare two database structure with SchemaCrawler and **most important** is it possible to **copy data from one database to other** and if there is no data for some columns just leave them empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alyona,

Please take a look at [schemacrawler-diff](https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/tree/master/schemacrawler-diff) for ideas on how to get started with programatically comparing database structures. Please note that this code is not production ready, nor is it supported, so you will to develop your own method of comparing databases, based on your needs.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: Thank you, following example you provided I compared two databases, but I got a bit weird result for `CHANGED` value. In second database I only added one column to table, but I got 1 `ADDED` and 6 `CHANGED` results even though I don't remember changing anything, why it reacted like this:

Comment: `/tables[flat] column flat was CHANGED to flat
/tables[flat]/columns[flat.number] column null was ADDED to flat.number
/tables[flat]/columns[flat.owner_name] column flat.owner_name was CHANGED to flat.owner_name
/tables[flat]/columns[flat.owner_surname] column flat.owner_surname was CHANGED to flat.owner_surname
/tables[flat]/columns[flat.area_size] column flat.area_size was CHANGED to flat.area_size
/tables[flat]/columns[flat.people_living] column flat.people_living was CHANGED to flat.people_living` etc...

Comment: Table Flat is empty, but it shows any column after added one as changed.